# Firebase Reserva de Asiento Bus Query

Tags: java, android, ios, firebase, kotlin

Quiero hacer una aplicación como el de ADO, para comprar tus boletos de bus para viajar, el problema ha surgido al momento de realizar el buscador de viajes disponibles en tal fecha, he pensado por horas y no encuentro la estructura ideal para lograr buscar varios viajes en una fecha indicada con su precio especifico, me explico, tu puedes comprar tu boleto para ir de un punto A a un punto D en una fecha indicada, pero como le hago para realizar la base de datos en firebase si habra ocasiones donde una persona comprara un boleto en el punto B para ir al C o desde el punto B para ir al D o quizas desde el punto A para ir al B , todos los viajes ocuparian el mismo camion, serian la misma fecha, a la misma hora y asi varios viajes a diferentes horas, digamos que cada viaje tiene 1 camion, 1 chofer y en un solo viaje que se hace, tiene varios origenes y varios destinos, cada origen destino con diferentes precios. ¿Alguien me recomienda una estructura para poder filtrar los viajes bien en firebase? No se me ocurre nada.

Comment: Ya sabes que tienes que poner algo para que te ayudemos... Pero se me ocurre crear *tramos* entre diferentes puntos que sean indivisibles, y un viaje esté compuesto por varios tramos.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que Firebase Real Database es una estructura JSON, por ehnde podría hacer algo como esto:

```
{
    "viajes":[
        "AtoB":{
            "precio":"",
            "disponibilidad":""
        },
        "AtoC":{
            "precio":"",
            "disponibilidad":""
        },
        "AtoD":{
            "precio":"",
            "disponibilidad":""
        },
        "BtoC":{
            "precio":"",
            "disponibilidad":""
        },
        "BtoD":{
            "precio":"",
            "disponibilidad":""
        }
    ],
    "reservas":[
        "01-02-2018":{
            "camionA":{
                "AtoB":"10",
                "AtoC":"5",
                "AtoD":"15",
                "BtoC":"5"
            },
            "camionB":{
                "AtoB":"0",
                "AtoC":"15"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

El primer nodo, seria algo como la lista de posibles rutas de la empresa, el segundo nodo ya se registrarían las reservas por fecha y por camiones así como las rutas que ocupan reserva en dichos camiones, claro, hay varias maneras de hacer esa estructura y mejorarla pero es un inicio.

Comment: Pero cada ruta tiene un precio diferente dependiendo desde donde se suban al camión , el punto D no tendrá el mismo precio si te subes en el punto A que si te subes en el punto B

Comment: en eso estoy claro, por eso ves que en el primer nodo se asignan precios de acuerdo al embarque y hacia donde se dirigen,por ejemplo AtoB, lo que significa que ese precio me aplica si subo en el punto a y me dirijo hacia el punto b